# iText7 C# MultiColumn Text

Tags: c#, text, itext7

I am working on implementing MultiColumn Text that span across multiple pages in IText 7 .NET. It would be great if anyone could provide an example in C# on how to implement this. The ColumnText which was available in iTextSharp is no more available in Itext7.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the [documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/3259) or take a look at [the examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/examples/chapter-3#2793-c03e01_newyorktimes.cs) before asking a question.

iText 7 has a huge improvement: you can create you document as if no colums are needed, and then simply introduce columns by adding a specific renderer:

```
float offSet = 36;
float columnWidth = (ps.GetWidth() - offSet * 2 + 10) / 3;
float columnHeight = ps.GetHeight() - offSet * 2;
//Define column areas
Rectangle[] columns = new Rectangle[] {
    new Rectangle(offSet - 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight),
    new Rectangle(offSet + columnWidth * 2 + 5, offSet, columnWidth, columnHeight)
};
document.SetRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
```